# unexpected "=" in operand

Tags: go, hugo

I am getting this error in a Hugo theme and have modified the code to use a simple example from the Hugo documentation and still get an error.

> unexpected "=" in operand

Hugo Version

> Hugo Static Site Generator v0.40.1 linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2018-04-25T17:16:11Z

Go Version

> go version go1.12 linux/amd64

I have copied this code directly from the [GoHugo - Append](https://gohugo.io/functions/append/) example.

Error

```
ERROR 2019/03/11 09:24:53 theme/partials/work.html : template: theme/partials/work.html:3: unexpected "=" in operand
```

Simplified Template

```
{{ partial "global-header.html" . }}

{{ $s := slice "a" "b" "c" }}
{{ $s = $s | append "d" "e" }}

<h1>David</h1>
```

I originally got the error in the [Hugo AirSpace](https://themes.gohugo.io//theme/airspace-hugo/) template at line 13 of the work.html partial.

Sample Line

```
{{ $categories = $categories | append .category }}
```

Full Template

```
{{ partial "global-header.html" . }}

<!-- Portfolio Start -->
<section id="portfolio-work">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="block">
              <div class="portfolio-menu">
                <ul>
                  {{ $categories := slice }}
                  {{ range .Site.Data.work.portfolio }}
                    {{ $categories = $categories | append .category }}
                  {{ end }}
                    <li class="filter" data-filter="all">Everything</li>
                  {{ range ( $categories | uniq ) }}
                    <li class="filter" data-filter=".{{ . }}">{{ . }}</li>
                  {{ end }}
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="portfolio-contant">
                <ul id="portfolio-contant-active">
                  {{ range .Site.Data.work.portfolio }}
                    <li class="mix {{ .category }}">
                      <a class="venobox" href="{{ $.Site.BaseURL }}{{ .image }}">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $.Site.BaseURL }}{{ .image }}" />
                        <div class="overly">
                          <div class="position-center">
                            <i class="fa fa-search fz-20"></i>
                            <h2>{{ .name }}</h2>
                            <p>{{ .description }}</p>
                          </div>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  {{ end }}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Clients Logo Section Start -->
<section id="clients-logo-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="block">
          <div id="clients-logo" class="owl-carousel">
            {{ range .Site.Data.work.clients }}
            <div class="clients-logo-img">
              <a href="{{ .url }}"><img src="{{ $.Site.BaseURL }}{{ .image }}" alt="Features"></a>
            </div>
            {{ end }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that my version of go was old and it needed updating to 1.11

I followed the instructions found here

[install-go-1-11-on-ubuntu](https://medium.com/@RidhamTarpara/install-go-1-11-on-ubuntu-18-04-16-04-lts-8c098c503c5f)

I had one slight variation, I used Go1.12 instead of 1.11

```
# From the docs
sudo tar -xvf go1.11.linux-amd64.tar.gz

# This is the latest version when I updated
sudo tar -xvf go1.12.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

I also had to update my version of hugo.

Any time I did the following

```
sudo apt-get install hugo
```

I ended up with version 40

I followed the instructions here to go to [version 53](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-hugo-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)  of GO